# Sending a row of a multidimensional array to a worksheet

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, multidimensional-array

I have a large Two-Dimensional (550 rows by 260 column) array and wish to send full rows of the array to a spread sheet (not in the same order as the array is in). I am stuck on picking up an individual row (say row 12) from the 2-D array and placing it on a worksheet. Do you set the destination to the resize the cell?

Please, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the following function:

```
Function Get2DArrayRow(arr2D As Variant, irow As Long) As Variant
    ReDim rowArr(LBound(arr2d, 2) To UBound(arr2d, 2)) As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    For j = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
        rowArr(j) = arr2D(irow, j)
    Next j
    Get2DArrayRow = rowArr
End Function
```

to be exploited as follows:

```
Dim rowArr As Variant

rowArr = Get2DArrayRow(arr2D, 12) '<-- retriev the 12th row of your 2D array
ActiveSheet.Range("A20").Resize(, UBound(rowArr)).Value = rowArr '<-- write in row 20 of currently active sheet the 12th row of your 2D array
```

where I assumed `arr2D` as the name of your 2D array

Comment: Please, though, Where is arr defined? Is it a temp array?

Comment: or is it meant to be arr2D?

Comment: sorry, I edited my code after pasting it here: `arr` was to be `arr2d`. see edited answer

Comment: Very ninja though. Thanks again